# Why does Luna Lovegood behave like that?

Tags: harry-potter

Luna Lovegood behaves like an innocent girl in whole Harry Potter series. She
thinks the dying Dobby is sleeping in *Harry Potter Deathly Hallows* Part 1:

> **Luna**: We should close his eyes. Don't you think? There. Now he could
> be **sleeping**.

Why does Luna Lovegood behave like that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Luna is not confused and thinks that Dobby is sleeping, she is saying that *with his eyes closed he could [be mistaken for] sleeping* (e.g that he looks restful in death).

She is, at this point, attempting to console Harry who is distraught by the death of his beloved Dobby, echoing the likes of [Matthew 9:24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%209&version=KJV):

> *Make room, for the girl is not dead* [said Jesus], *but sleeping.*

Comment: [Death as Sleep: The (Mis)use of a Biblical Metaphor](https://digitalcommons.andrews.edu/jats/vol28/iss1/3/)

Comment: @I'Robot - in this instance I believe she is referring to the metaphor of death *looking like sleep*, rather than it's biblical allusions but yes, the point is well made.

Comment: Do you have a reference that Rowling was intentionally referencing Matthew 24:9, or is that just your own interpretation?

Comment: @TylerH - It's a pretty common trope and one that significantly predates the Bible. I was merely using it as an illustration.

Comment: @Valorum I recognize it as extremely common, but I don't recognize all uses as originating from the Bible in particular; it seems an inherently discoverable metaphor that doesn't rely on knowledge from any particular real-world religion. Maybe instead of "echoing Matthew 24:9" it would be more apt to say "this metaphor is so common it exists as far back as the Bible:" or something.

Answer (score 4):

Sleeping/ asleep, resting in peace etc are well known famous euphemisms of death. The word *dead* is too blunt to describe someone you love or respect.

This is just well-mannered English. There's no issue with Luna Lovegood's behavior.

Comment: Luna Lovegood is love.